# How to print cursor records?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I have tried to print cursor records, but I can't. Below code, I have tried.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR CUR_EMP IS
      SELECT *
        FROM EMP
       WHERE Deptno = &DNO;

   V_REC  CUR_EMP%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN CUR_EMP;

   LOOP
      FETCH CUR_EMP INTO V_REC;

      EXIT WHEN CUR_EMP%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'Record No:'
         || CUR_EMP%ROWCOUNT
         || ' '
         || V_REC.ENAME
         || ' 
                         '
         || V_REC.SAL);
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE CUR_EMP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it as you did:

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor cur_emp is select * from emp
  3      where deptno = &dno;
  4    v_rec  cur_emp%rowtype;
  5  begin
  6    open cur_emp;
  7    loop
  8      fetch cur_emp into v_rec;
  9      exit when cur_emp%notfound;
 10
 11      dbms_output.put_line('Record no: ' || cur_emp%rowcount ||' '|| v_rec.ename);
 12    end loop;
 13    close cur_emp;
 14  end;
 15  /
Enter value for dno: 10
old   3:     where deptno = &dno;
new   3:     where deptno = 10;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.            --> there's no output
```

But, if you enable output ...

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
```

... and run that code again:

```
SQL> /
Enter value for dno: 10
old   3:     where deptno = &dno;
new   3:     where deptno = 10;
Record no: 1 CLARK                             --> oh yes, here they are!
Record no: 2 KING
Record no: 3 MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

So, `set serveroutput on` in SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer, maybe even some more tools which support it), or enable it in your GUI. Because, that code should run properly (of course, if `WHERE` condition is met).

---

Also, consider using cursor `FOR` loop which is easier to maintain as Oracle does most of the *dirty* job (declaring cursor variable, opening cursor, taking care about exiting the loop, closing the cursor) for you:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_emp in (select rownum rn, e.* from emp e where deptno = &dno) loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line('Record no: ' || cur_emp.rn ||' '|| cur_emp.ename);
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /
Enter value for dno: 10
old   2:   for cur_emp in (select rownum rn, e.* from emp e where deptno = &dno) loop
new   2:   for cur_emp in (select rownum rn, e.* from emp e where deptno = 10) loop
Record no: 1 CLARK
Record no: 2 KING
Record no: 3 MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I wish SO had a 'like' button.  As I was reading the question I was formulating my answer, only to see you had already responded exactly as I was planning.   :-)

Comment: "Like" on SO is, I guess, called "upvote", @EdStevens :)